# Unable to install GithubCopilot extension in Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio

**Unable to install GithubCopilot extension in Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise**

Hello geeks, I have visual studio 2022 enterprise in my computer and  in my GitHub account copilot  is approved  but can't install in visual studio
in visual studio extension it's not showing  GitHub copilot

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot

Comment: Yeah I can't see it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the version of your visual studio 2022 ,
after updateing visual studio entreprise from version 17.0.5 to the latest 17.1.3 , i could install Github Copilot (the documentaion says minimim version is *17.1*)
hope this could help you

Comment: thanks  also i have updated the visual studio enterprise 2022  now GitHub copilot is working